# citation with page number does not work

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, cross-referencing, citing

i want to cite some books as references and add the page number to the reference,
for example i have this bibliography entry :

```
@book{ref2,
title={Introduction to Information Systems: Supporting and Transforming Business},
author={Rainer, R.K. and Cegielski, C.G.},
isbn={9780470473528},     
year={2010},
publisher={John Wiley \& Sons}
}
```

i want to refer to the page xi, or page 4, like this :

```
R.K. Rainer and C.G. Cegielski. Introduction to Information Systems :
Supporting and Transforming Business. John Wiley & Sons, 2010. p. 4.
```

after some searches i found that this can be done by adding some arguments to cite command, like this:

```
\cite[options]{ref2}
```

i tried it with different way that i found while searching:

```
\cite[chap.~1,p.~4]{ref2}
\cite[p.~4]{ref2}
\cite[extras={,p.~4}]{ref2}
\cite[extras={p.~4}]{ref2}
```

but it is not showing, it just shows the bib entry (title, author, publisher ...), i tried to changed the bibliography style but same (i used plain style, ieeetr and alpha).
for the compilation i think it is working because when changing the style the result changes.

any suggestions? 
and thank you^^.

Comment: You want the page number in the bibliography / reference list for a book? This is unusual. Most bibliography styles are set up so that you `\cite` the page number in the main body of the document (e.g., `\cite[4]{ref2}`) but just have the bibliographical information in the bibliography (which is used to provide the necessary information so that another person could look up that book). That is why page number are important for journal articles, which make up a portion of the journal issue, but not for books. In the citation it is important to give the page number(s) where appropriate.

Comment: but what if i want to tell that this information (the cited information) is deduced from the page number X from the Book Y, it would be easy to the reader to refer to the information in that book.

for example (... Android is based on Linux Kernel [1] ...),

and the entry [1] is :

[1] Author, Android programming.Publisher, 20XX. p. 256.

like this the reader will refer directly to the page number 256 in the book "Android programming" to confirm that information.

Comment: And what happens if you use the same book to make a second point, and that point comes from page 123? I still don't understand why you wouldn't want the page number to be part of the citation (so, `\cite[256]{ref2}` --> `[1, p. 256]`); however, I never work in areas where numeric systems like this are in use, so my opinion probably does not count for much....

Comment: i'll create another entry for it, but anyway i think that using page numbers in citations is better. i think it is a typography rule since it is supported natively by LaTeX. thank you (y).

Answer (score 5):

With the `plain` bibliography style, I was able to use

```
\cite[pg.100]{ref}
```

It worked perfectly. It shows up as this in the document:

> [5, pg.100]

However, I have no solution for the other bibliography styles.

Answer (score 1):

Try `\bibliographystyle{unsrt}` with a BibTeX entry like this:

```
@book{Test, 
    author= {Test, A.},
    year=2016,
    title= {A Book About BibTeX},
    publisher= {A Publisher},
    note = "pg. 4"
}
```

Then simply `\cite{Test}`.

For more info on BibTeX entries and required fields, have a look at Section 3.1 of the [BibTeX documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/bibtex/base/btxdoc.pdf) `:)`.

Comment: ah `note` is added to the last, this is what i am searching for, it is just a workaround, is there any way to made it by a latex command because latex will choose the typography rules of page referencing (for example putting just the 'p' character)

Comment: In this case, LaTex will simply print whatever you type in the quote marks, so you can put p., pg., page etc. I don't know if there is a specific LaTeX command for what you have in mind. It may depend on the style you have chosen for your bibliography.

Comment: yes that is it, it will print just whatever i type in the quote, what i want is to just tell him that i want to refer to the page number X, and latex will print it using the standard typography rules.